# "My personal opinion is..." Is it always pointless to use the words "personal" and "personally"?

Tags: word-usage, redundancy

Is this kind of redundancy acceptable in both speech and writing, formal and informal ?  Would the following sentences have their meaning changed if we omitted "personal" or "personally" ?  Would they lose anything at all ?

> - She is a personal friend of mine.
> - It's my personal opinion....
> - Personally, I would advise you...
> - The manager said he will examine the matter personally.
> - Personally, I don't care whether...
> - I have a personal interest in the matter.

Comment: At first I thought the answer would be "Personally is useless noise", but it turns out that's not the case. +1.

Comment: of mine, it's my, I would, he will, I don't, I have - all these are pretty clear and if anybody misconstrues who is being referenced, then that's their own personal problem ;)

Comment: Sure, you can always drop them. But, English is **packed with** repetition and filler.  You might as well just say "Oh, I observe that English is packed with repetition, ambiguity and filler."  Answer - "yeah, that's right."  You know?

Comment: In short, the added implied meaning in every case is: *this is not influenced by the group*. It's not redundant, although sometimes it's applied inappropriately, in my personal opinion.

Comment: I don't think most people really want to make a distinction  when they say "my personal opinion."  Maybe it is a habit just as some people say "In my humble opinion".  Do you think they really find their opinion is humble ?

Comment: When I say "in my humble opinion" that's gentle self-mockery.  My opinion is usually not humble, and I know it.

Comment: @Luis IMHO I think adding the word "humble" is sometimes warranted. I most frequently use it to express deference or respect when offering an opposing view. "In my opinion" acknowledges that it is not a provable fact, but a judgment call. "In my humble opinion" implies, for example, a strong possibility that the opinion isn't as well-founded as another's, that it represents mere preference, not fundamental belief, and/or that no offense is intended by it. **EDIT:** I have used it to make sarcasm more obvious, too. Good call, Warren.

Comment: "The manager said he will examine the matter personally." will lose implied meaning if *personally* is removed. Managers examine many matters, but if they do so *personally*, it's much more involved.

Comment: My girlfriend insists that adding this sort of detail will improve the power of you message. I find it irritating but it can influence the herd.

Comment: I disagree with the upvoted answer; these are all technically redundant and should be removed.

Comment: I have a number of opinions. Many are shared and not developed by me; but some are personal opinions that I generated on my own. A manager may delegate investigations and then review a report of results; or the investigation could be personal. In the latter case, there would likely be some detailed questions, etc., not considered by the delegate. But whether or not an author has an intention when using 'personal'...?

Answer (score 111, accepted):

Generally, the word *personal* is used in these scenarios to indicate (or just emphasize) that the matter is, in fact, personal (from themselves without any other context to affect it). Let's take a look at your example sentences.

> She is a **personal** friend of mine.

Without the "personal" there, there's no telling exactly how they're friends. A friend from work? A friend from school? Calling the friend a *personal* friend implies a somewhat less superficial relationship.

> It's my **personal** opinion...

A person can have multiple opinions on a matter. For example, a climate scientist's *professional* opinion on whether global warning is an anthropogenic phenomenon would probably be that the evidence points towards it being so, while personally they may think it's just the perpetuation of natural climate cycles.

And as some others have pointed out, a public figure might prefix her opinion with "personal" when talking publicly in order to separate her own opinion from the opinion of her company or organization.

> **Personally**, I would advise you...

A lawyer might give his friend who isn't a client some off-the-record advice on what will happen should they take a lawsuit or proceeding. A police officer might give a person he's talking to some unofficial guidance as to how to deal with a charge he's filing.

> The manager said he will examine the matter **personally**.

If the manager were *not* examining the matter personally, he might examine it via one of his subordinates who would give him a report of the matter.

> **Personally**, I don't care whether...

Again, a person may be forced to assume a particular impersonal opinion by virtue of their occupation. A traffic officer might not *personally* care that somebody's driving 20 km/h above the speed limit on a highway when everybody else is 15 over, but professionally he could never say that.

> I have a **personal** interest in the matter.

If you advocate against pirating a game developer's games because you have stock investments in their company and don't want to see your investment lost, that's a business interest. If you advocate against pirating those games just because you think piracy is wrong and people shouldn't be stealing, that's a moral interest. But if you advocate against pirating those games because you like that developer's games and want to continue to have more games from that developer to play, that's a personal interest.

---

So yes, the word *personal* is indeed useful in these contexts, and not completely redundant either.

Comment: To extend this answer with an important example: "In my *personal* opinion..." is quite often used by representatives of organizations when speaking with the media. This distinguishes the statement that follows this qualifier from one which truly represents the stance of the organization they represent. It's a precaution to prevent their words from mis-representing their organization.

Comment: Re. the last example's "you have stock" scenario: it might be described as a *personal interest*, though a *vested interest* would better describe it.

Comment: I suppose you're right.

Comment: I agree with most your examples. However, like "free gift", "personal friend" is redundant: friendship is, by definition, a personal matter. The manager examining something personally is also redundant: either the manager examines it or he gets somebody else to examine it; in the second case, he cannot truthfully say "I examined it."

Comment: @DavidRicherby I can provide a counter example. Say you are a radio show host. If the show has a regular guest who visits they are said to be a friend of the show. This person may not be a personal friend of yours. That would imply that the host spends a good deal of time with this person while not on the air. Most people have people like this in their lives. You couldn't really call this person an acquaintance because you are a little more familiar with each other than that but, for whatever reason, you do not socialize outside of a certain setting.

Comment: @krowe Delete "personal" and your comment still makes sense, so "personal" is redundant. The friend of my hypothetical radio show may or may not be a friend of mine. If they are an actual friend of mine, I can say "They are my friend" with no need for "personal", since there is no other kind of friend a person can have; if they are not my friend, I can say "They are a regular guest on my show".

Comment: @DavidRicherby That was a thing to say. <-- This sentence makes sense but it provides very little meaning. Just because a sentence still makes sense without a word doesn't make the added words redundant.

Comment: @DavidRicherby I just showed you the counter. I used the radio host as an example because a radio host doesn't necessarily actually ever talk to the person they interview without an audience. That is not personal is it?

Comment: @krowe My claim was that "personal" is redundant in your example of a regular guest of a radio show not necessarily being a "personal friend" of the host. Obviously, the word is not redundant in all contexts but I never claimed that. (There are several non-redundant examples in the original question; your example of "That's a personal question" is also excellent.)

Comment: @DavidRicherby Your original claim was that "personal friend" is always redundant. It is not. Among other things, it may be used to distinguish between a *family* friend and a personal one. Both are friends, but one is friends specifically with your person, while the other you are friendly with in more of a group context--closer than an acquaintance but not quite yet a personal, close, or intimate friend. It may also indicate how you became or stayed friends: by personal choice? or because you were thrown together by work, school, etc.?

Comment: @Wlerin A family friend is somebody who is a friend of most members of the family. Friendship is *always* by personal choice. Merely being friendly with somebody (i.e., having cordial interactions with them) does not make them friends: some of the people who you work or study with become friends; others remain just as acquaintances.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Friendship is *not* always by personal choice, at least not active personal choice (choice producing action), which is what I meant. Obviously you choose to identify that person as a friend, but this doesn't require the same level of personal involvement. That said.... Everyone's definition of friend will differ slightly, and cover slightly different semantic ranges. Perhaps 'personal friend' is not a useful distinction for you, but it is for me, and I do not think I am alone in this.

Comment: I have an account here just so I could upvote some worthy questions/answers but I felt compelled to specifically comment on this well thought out and comprehensive answer.

Comment: @DavidRicherby Also, I know I'm pointing this out late, but "free gift" isn't necessarily redundant either. A gift may have no *monetary* price but still have strings attached - for example, a campaign donation. Is it still "free"? Arguably no.

Answer (score 16):

*Personal* is being used in at least three non-redundant ways in these examples

- To distinguish a personal opinion from another opinion, for example a [professional opinion](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Opinion), given by a professional person. *It's my personal opinion....*
- As emphasis that the opinion is mine, and may differ from others. *Personally, I would advise you...*
- To express a connection with the matter *I have a personal interest in the matter*.

The manager *will examine the matter personally*, rather than assign it to a subordinate.

The only case that appears redundant is *She is a personal friend of mine.*

Comment: If the manager assigned the examination to a subordinate, the manager didn't examine it. So two two options are "I will examine it" or "I will get somebody else to examine it."  "I will examine it personally" is a redundant way of saying the first option.

Comment: Agree with the first sentence, but in human behavior and language there are often more options than the logical ones. A manager can equally behave as though they are their department, and when they say "I'll do this or that" they mean "My department will ...". Hence distinguishing the case where they will carry out the task themselves.

Comment: (+1) I would interpret “I will examine the matter personally” as a way to express concern or sympathy for the other party and acknowledge there is an important problem. By contrast, “I will examine the matter” could be slightly dismissive or at least neutral.

Answer (score 5):

Consider a person whose job it is to be the public face of an organization. Naturally, he has opinions of his own -- i.e., his personal opinions. However, because of his position as an official spokesman for his employer, whenever he makes a pronouncement, especially among strangers, he must make it clear whether he is speaking for his employer or for himself. In the latter case, he would use the "personally" formulation.

Answer (score 5):

One point that seems to be missing in the other answers is that in some of these examples, the function of the word “personal” or “personally” seems to be [connotative](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connotation_(semiotics)). For example, opinions are arguably always personal. Taking a (too) literal view of the meaning of the word, it would therefore appear that “personal opinion” is a redundant phrase.

But at the same time, the adjective does provide some color or nuances that should be readily perceived by most English speakers. In this case, beside the point others made about the distinction between speaking in a professional capacity or not, it might be a way to implicitly stress the validity of other opinions regarding the issue at hand.

Similarly, “I will examine the matter personally” shows a particular concern or sympathy for the other party or might be a way to express respect (“I'll do it *personally* because you're important”). You can only ever pretend *you* looked into something if you did it *personally* but just saying “I will look at it” sounds more distant or even slightly dismissive. (“I will examine the matter” also sounds a bit odd to me, so “I will examine the matter personally” could perhaps be interpreted as a conventional expression).

Answer (score 4):

In speaking, the addition of 'personal' to 'my opinion' is a tactic of discourse. You might say 'my *personal*' opinion to poke an interlocutor who is not taking responsibility for her own opinions, but is rather claiming to spout universal truth. Or, you might say it rather pompously in mock modesty, to emphasize that the people listening to you are obliged to respect your point of view, because you are in authority.

The bullets in the question range across several different usages; some are variations on this, others convey other nuances. Perhaps others will fill in other aspects.

Answer (score 3):

This word is often used purely as a "filler", but sometimes is used as a way to show emphasis to distinguish the person's views from the organisation they work for, or from any other affiliation they may be perceived to have.

However, this usage may also sometimes be used merely out of politeness, especially in British English. In British English it is common to put a view across in a manner that is tentative or even non-committal, in order to appear less forceful, and less aggressive, especially in formal or polite contexts.

Answer (score 1):

It is redundant if the assumption about the personal statement is obvious, like when two girls figthing and one would say "(Personally, )I don't care whether you like me or not". 
However it gives an emotional flavour to the sentence and emphasize that I really don't care...

Answer (score 0):

Your question highlights a specific example that may use *personal* unnecessarily or incorrectly - then follows it with a general question. There are some uses of *personal* that are incorrect, superfluous or ridiculous, as your question shows.

A person can hold opinions they form for themselves (rare) or that they get from their community (common). When people say they are expressing their *personal opinion*, they are almost certainly unaware that it isn't true - they are using a phrase they heard to qualify an opinion they heard - without analyzing either. They could correctly say: "*... my opinion ...*". *My personal opinion* should be reserved for those opinions earned not copied.

Perhaps the question should qualify the example with a suitable context.

Comment: Except that the listed usages aren't incorrect or unnecessary at all, as demonstrated by the above answers.